# Dash columns doesn't match grid system

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

in the Dash layout docs, it is said that:

```
"An integer 1,...,12. Column will span this many of the 12 grid columns. For a half width column, set width=6, for a third width column, set width=4, and so on."
```

therefore, When I defined 3 columns in a single row, each with `width=4`, I expected each to catch a third of the screen:

```
navbar = dbc.Navbar(
            dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 1',style={'backgroundColor':'blue'}), width=4),
                    dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 2',style={'backgroundColor':'green'}), width=4),
                    dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 3',style={'backgroundColor':'yellow'}), width=4)])
        ,color="#ff4d4d")
```

but the result is very different:
[image]

as you can see, the three cols clamp in the beginning of the screen, not willing to stretch the whole way. what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `'display':'block'` instead of using flex:

```
 dbc.Navbar(
            dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 1',style={'backgroundColor':'blue'}), width=4),
                    dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 2',style={'backgroundColor':'green'}), width=4),
                    dbc.Col(html.H1('Column 3',style={'backgroundColor':'yellow'}), width=4)])
        ,color="#ff4d4d", style={'display':'block'})])
```

[image]